# An issue with assigning a value to a vector type struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

In this program I want to convert a graph. As an input I should get an adjacency matrix, store the graph as a list of neighbors in a vector type struct, and output the graph as a adjacency matrix again. I'm having an issue assigning values to the vector. How can I store the input as a vector and is it doable at all?

This is my full code. Thank you in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct edge
{
    int x,y;
};
int n,a[1024][1024];
vector<edge> v;
void read()
{
    int temp,k=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            cin>>temp;
            if(temp==1)
            {
                // Here I want to make v[k].x=i
                // Here I want to make v[k].y=j
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
void print()
{
    int k=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(v[k].x==i||v[k].y==j)
            {
                cout<<1<<" ";
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<0<<" ";
                k++;
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    read();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<v[i].x<<" "<<v[i].y<<endl;
    //print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector and then actually try to fill the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to write a simple 2 or 3 line program to familiarize yourself with how `vector` and other classes work.  Once you get the program to work, then you apply those changes to your larger program that you're trying to develop.

If you did that, you should have quickly discovered the `vector::push_back` function provides one way to add an entry to the vector:

```
edge ed;
ed.x = i;
ed.y = j;
v.push_back(ed);
```

Also, another good thing about creating a small program is that you get to flush out any errors you may have made.  For example, since the vector is empty, accessing element `k` as your original attempt showed may have crashed, thus indicating that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Since you have the value of `n` early in the program, you might want to include the code `v.reserve(n);` so that your vector `v` will not have to do memory reallocation as elements are added to it. This is strictly an efficiency consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tip, as I don't have a lot of experience in programming.